# Is NLog work with customErrors?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, error-handling, nlog, custom-errors

when i use `<customErrors mode="Off"/>` and i have an error on the screen it writes to log file but when i use `<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"/>` then i see my custom error page but error not catches but logger :-/

Answer (score 0):

I think this depends on how you are capturing the error from NLog if you are only capturing undhandled exceptions then NLog would not work in this case because the all exceptions that are not explicitly handled will be assigned the custom errors exception handler.

Thus since they are being handled NLog won't log them.